# Use a database to handle application Licensing

Tags: c#, sql, database

I was wondering if it was possible, and if so how can, someone efficiently add a licensing aspect to an application using a database? For example if someone has a customer that has an application developed in C# that interacts with a database (sends a query and gets databack), would it be possible to have it so that if that database did not have a "License" the C# application would not function? Ideally what I am trying to do is be able to develop several applications that interact with the same database and instead of having each application manage it's own license I want to use the database since all pipes lead back to the ocean.

If any more information is needed please let me know.

Comment: Are you asking to use the database license(the license a company has with Microsoft, for SQL Server), or are you asking to add a table to the database to check against for a valid license?

Comment: Sure its possible. It just likely would be slower then dirt.

Comment: Sounds like you want to add license info to the database?  You'd have to link the clients with login info or a serial # of some sort...

Comment: @Johnie Karr, I am indeed asking about adding a table to the database to check against for a valid license.

To Ramhound,  I am aware that speed is a potential issue, but I am going to try an make it as efficient as possible.  All in all it can't be that slow in the first place...I hope.

Comment: Databases are for storing data. If your license is data it can be stored in a database. It is no different than storing in registry or in a file.

Answer (score 0):

I actually am working with this right now. It's still in a development phase so I do not know how things will work in production. (Though I target very specific set of customers so chances are small that I end up with thousands of users)

What I did was, I added a login screen to my C# WPF application where you'll fill in your password etc. Then this information is send using a SOAP webservice to the server where it'll validate the license. If this function returns true I allow the user to log in, store the credentials of the customer in RAM and for every request my app makes it sends these along, only returning data if license is valid (to prevent people from 'hacking' by simply never shutting down the computer (I have a time-based license)). The way I do it works perfectly, little to no noticeable delays (then again it's still in beta).

I don't know if your apps are licensed seperately or anything so that part you'll have to figure out for yourself.